# How can I create a self update codepipeline?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk, aws-codepipeline, cicd

I am using codepipeline as CI/CD pipeline by using CDK.

I'd like to make the pipeline update by itself so I tried to create one stage in the pipeline to update the pipeline itself by running `cdk deploy`  command.

In order to make the self update work, I need to specify a parameter selfMutation in codepipeline construct: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.pipelines.CodePipeline.html#selfmutation

but this property only exists in cdk v2 not v1 ( I am using cdk 1.84.0 ). What is the equivalent property in v1?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The CDK pipelines package also exists in v1.

CDK Pipelines are different from aws-codepipeline.Pipeline. It's build on top of it and allows you to deploy CDK apps with CodePipeline.

More information about CDK pipelines and what they are: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/cdk-pipelines-continuous-delivery-for-aws-cdk-applications/

Documentation for CDK pipelines in CDKv1: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v1/docs/pipelines-readme.html

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I wonder why they need a separate class for CDK pipeline. Isn't it just run `cdk deploy` to deploy a CDK project?

Comment: No, it's a whole different API with a lot of abstractions over CodePipeline. For one, it allows for very easy cross-environment deployment, as well as self-mutation and uploading of assets.

Comment: Do you know why it is called CDK pipeline? Does it mean cloudformation doesn't support it? I am not sure about why it relates to CDK only.

Comment: Because it's for deploying CDK apps. Check the link in the answer, it explains what it is.

Comment: The link explains how to deploy a self-mutating pipeline. But the question is why it is specific to CDK application? Can I make it work for any application, like cf, terraform etc?